# Xcode doesn't allow new files to show in editor in group

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I opened up a recently made Xcode project. I am extremely frustrated that I can't add new images(.png) in the group "images".

Even worse, when I delete a folder to replace it with a new folder, I can't get the reference back and it autosaves.

1. Delete group images (Images->Asia->landscape.png, buldings.png)
2. Create Group Images
3. Drag subdirectory (Asia) underneath images folder in xcode copy references
4. Doesn't appear ?! in xcode.

Comment: There is a difference between a Group and a Folder Reference. Which do you want?

Comment: Here is the direct method I used from originally settup the images folder, before I made new images. "The flag images are located in the book's examples in the images/FlagQuizImages folder. Perform the following steps to add these to the project: 1. In Xcode, right click the Flagquiz group (folder) and select New Group. 2 Enter images in the new group's name. 3 Open the images/FlagquizImages folder in Finder, then drag the subfolder for the six world regions on the images group you just created in Xcode. In the sheet that appears ensure Copy if needed is checked." Now I can's see the regions

Answer (score 0):

Delete old reference(folder) and create new Group and then add images it will show.Drag your images to this group.

Comment: Yes, and when I do that, the old images are still in the system during run time. How do I find the references? I would like to delete old references.

Comment: Try to add same names you can find them. Otherwise name them differently.

Comment: I had to use clean on the targets